# What does this simple code do (newbie)?

Tags: php, request

I'm digging up a code I used to write with a friend of mine.
It's been a while and I can't figure out what the purpose was of this snippet:

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : "home.php";
```

It's nearly the only code in that php-file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is `ternary operator` that checks for the condition that whether the page variable is set either by `POST` method or `GET` method.`REQUEST` method can check both.and if it is set then the request page value `$_REQUEST['page']` will be assigned to `$page` variable or else defaultly 'home.php' will be assigned to the `$page` same as

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])){
     $page = $_REQUEST['page'] ;
} else {
     $page = "home.php" ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])){
  $page = $_REQUEST['page'] ;
} else {
  $page = "home.php" ;
}
```

It is called `Ternary operator`. Provides some readability for you code.

```
(expr) ? (value if true) : (value if false)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to read a bit about [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) to understand why and when you use $_REQUEST
Then check the method [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
And finally the sintax for your if statement wich is

> if(condition) doSomething else doSomething;

So basically you check if $_REQUEST['page'] has a value (is not null or unset).
If it has, you put that value into the variable $page. Else, you set $page with the value "home.php.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is a ternary operator.  Its a single line if statement.

Read it like this

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
    $page = 'home.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the *ternary operator*, the form is:

```
test ? true-value : false-value
```

It evaluates the part of the expression before `?`. If it's true, the `true-value` expression is evaluated and returned, otherwise the `false-value` expression is evaluated and returned.

So your code checks whether `$_REQUEST['page']` is set. If it is, `$page` is set to its value, otherwise `$page` is set to `home.php`.

`$_REQUEST` is a predefined variable that contains the parameters set from either the URL (like `$_GET`) or form fields (like `$_POST'`).